# Discord Js, Create an invitation from the voice channel i'm in

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently creating a discord bot for my server, and i want to create a "vocal" command that share in the channel i made the command, the voice channel invitation i am in.
I tried different things but impossible to have something that works. I would be grateful if you can help me. Thanks.
Check below :

```
    {
        let channel = member.voice.channel;
        channel.createInvite({unique: true})
        .then(invite => { channel.send("Hey! I've created you an invite: https://discord.gg/" + invite.code)
        })
    }
```

`` member.voice.channel.createInvite().then(invite => message.channel.send(`Join us ! ;) : \n\nhttps://discord.gg/${invite.code}`)); ``

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code works for me. The only thing I did was access the message the command came in.

Comment: I mean, when i'm connected to a voice channel, the bot can't grab the id and create an invitation to this voice channel.

Comment: I literally used your code only with a `message` in front of it: "message.member.voice.channel.createInvite().then(invite => message.channel.send(`Join us ! ;) : \n\nhttps://discord.gg/${invite.code}`));"